# Yii2: get value of attribute that has a behavior

Tags: php, model, yii2

I'm using the TimestampBehaviour like this:

```php
public function behaviors() {
    return [
        [
            'class' => \yii\behaviors\TimestampBehavior::className(),
            'createdAtAttribute' => 'usr_date_added',
            'updatedAtAttribute' => 'usr_date_modified',
            'value' => new \yii\db\Expression('UTC_TIMESTAMP()'),
        ],
    ];
}
```

Then if access it through the authenticated user like this...

```
Yii::$app->user->identity->usr_date_modified;
```

...I get the expression instead of the actual value:

```
object(yii\db\Expression)#38 (2) {
  ["expression"]=>
  string(15) "UTC_TIMESTAMP()"
  ["params"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```

If I do it like this I correctly get the actual value:

```
$user = app\models\User::findOne(51);
echo $user->usr_date_modified;
```

Why is that? And how can I get the actual value through the identity property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that I have modified an attribute and then called the `save()` method. You would think it should then hold the actual value after calling `save()` but it doesn't - I guess because doing the `UPDATE` query the database doesn't return the value. You need to call the `refresh()` method (see [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-behaviors-timestampbehavior.html)) to make another `SELECT` query to get the new value. So you would need to do it like this:

```php
Yii::$app->user->identity->usr_last_access = gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s');
Yii::$app->user->identity->save();
Yii::$app->user->identity->refresh();
```

Answer (score 0):

The `value` while not saved in the database holds the information about how this actual value should be created - in your case it uses `UTC_TIMESTAMP()` MySQL function that will be called at the moment of saving this object into DB.

When you are retrieving object already saved in the database it takes whatever has been saved there (in your case the result of this MySQL function), so it gives you actual timestamp.

Before saving the object there is no point of checking this value.

Comment: But the record already exists - mind you, it is the user that is logged in. Now I see that it only gives the expression because I update a "last access" field in the model - if I skip that I returns the value just fine. But I do call the save() method after setting that "last access" attribute, so it should still give me the real value I would say...